# Stata: Concatenate string variable on by condition

Tags: stata

I'm creating a variable called result in the following sample data which shows a 'W' if a bet was a win and 'L' if it was a loss.

How can I concatenate this variable with itself on a row by row basis in strict order by timestamp for each username?

```
clear
input str16 username str40 betdate winnings
player1 "12NOV2008:19:04:01" -10
player1 "12NOV2008:12:03:44" 50
player2 "07NOV2008:14:03:33" -50
player2 "05NOV2008:09:00:00" -100
end

generate double timestamp=clock(betdate,"DMY hms") 
format timestamp %tc

cap drop result
generate result = "L"
replace result = "W" if (winnings >0)

cap drop resulthistory
generate resulthistory = ""
replace resulthistory = concat(resulthisory + result), by(USERNAME timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers should note that the last line of the question is fantasy syntax; the rest would work.

This may be what you seek. Note that as you read in the data afresh, the variables you `capture drop` can't exist.

```
clear
input str16 username str40 betdate winnings
player1 "12NOV2008:19:04:01" -10
player1 "12NOV2008:12:03:44" 50
player2 "07NOV2008:14:03:33" -50
player2 "05NOV2008:09:00:00" -100
end

gen double timestamp=clock(betdate,"DMY hms") 
format timestamp %tc

gen result = cond(winnings > 0, "W", "L") 

bysort username (timestamp): gen resulthistory = result[1] 
by username : replace resulthistory = resulthistory[_n-1] + result if _n > 1 
by username : replace resulthistory = resulthistory[_N] 

list
```